# Is using logic and being sceptic allowed in islam?

Tags: halal-haram, kufr

> sceptic : a person inclined to question or doubt accepted opinions.

So is scepticism allowed in islam. Will a sceptic muslim go to heaven? And also a person who uses logic.

The one who doesn't reject Allah's exists.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

My answer is "yes but... ":
Islam is based on the faith that Muhammad (p.b.u.h) is a prophet and the Qur'an is the message he received from God through the intermediate of Jibril. Putting this into question may be allowed but it is not inside Islam. The Holy Qur'an declines any doubt and warns that disbelief is harmful.
For the rest of it, doubt on teachings is allowed and also practised at least in Hanifa and Maliki school. Shariah can be reviewed, and we are in general not bound to accept all teachings as long as they are not applicable law.
Critical thinking inside Islam can have benefit. Many things have been thought and thought over, and much will be right and some conclusions may be wrong. Also if you or I think, some conclusions may be right and some wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Allah and Mohammad teach muslims to be smart, strong and clever. Logic is a strong basement for all of these and definitely should be used by muslims from all over the world. Muslims are supposed to be smart and as a consequence sceptical to things they don't know or don't understand. They shouldn't trust everyone, or everything they hear or read just by a word. Being sceptical, asking questions, looking for answers - these are the best ways to learn the world we live in and become a better muslim.

Answer (score 0):

Yes , and as a confirmation to these apparent answers, we shall say that God himself asks Muslims and non Muslims to reflect on qu'ran and criticize it if their is anything wrong which may show if that book is delivered by God or just fabricated by a human being